# is there a way to capture & handle "Previous" using Google Actions & Media Player

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm using the `MediaObject` responses to play audio in my Dialogflow driven Action. At the end of each audio clip, I'm using the `mediaStatus` callback to advance to another episode in a predefined playlist. As a result, users should be able to navigate forwards / backwards.

On Alexa, Next/Previous are built in intents, but my understanding is that with Google Actions, you have to handle these manually.

When testing on my Google Home, I *can* intercept "Hey Google, Next" and advance to the next audio clip. However, I can't properly intercept "Hey Google, Previous." Whenever I try, the audio will restart / break the conversation. Google Home seems to be handling this intent on it's own & does not throw any console output (so it's happening on device perhaps?)

Does anyone have a reliable solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

If your action is still running, then the user just has to say "next" or "previous". Saying, "OK, Google..." will take it out of the context of your action and then it is up to the assistant to decide if it wants to handle the user request. Dialogflow provides follow-up intents for "next" and "previous" that you can add to your agent.

Comment: Leon, since I'm using the mediaplayer, I don't think I can leave the mike open with a mediaObject + my playlist does auto advance properly.  

I have a list of synonyms for "previous" including go back / earlier story / etc. and those generally get picked up properly, but previous always restarts the audio.

oddly, my intents are intercepting volume commands (max volume, louder, softer) and treating these are input.text events instead of the device handling them properly.

Comment: This is currently by design when using a media response. You can file a feature request: https://developers.google.com/actions/support/

Answer (score -1):

I'm working with `MediaResponse` as you too,

Actually I can implemented features : `Next|Previous`, manually.

The **logic is so simple**, so you don't need to get help from `Google`.

The logic should be :

1 - Had `song list`

2 - Define the `selected song index`

3 - Play the **first song with `selected song index = 0`**

4 - Next|Previous feature just be increase|decrease selected song index (`selectedSongIndex++|selectedSongIndex--`)

*p/s : You can define phrase like "please next" "next" "next song" ... with your Custom Intents, to catch it*